# Do Spark tranformation and action tasks work on the same serialized copy of code

Tags: java, apache-spark, thread-safety, rdd

Suppose I have the following:

rdd.mapPartition(func). When this gets executed by tasks inside an executor, do they get only one serialized copy of the function or each task gets one copy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each task gets one copy. However, I would like to not make my codes depend on this behavior.